# Recursive binary search - segmentation fault

Tags: c++, algorithm, binary-search

My code is below. I have coded binary search to get to know it but every time I go to run it, it shows something called segmentation fault

```
   #include<stdio.h>

int Bin_Search(int a[],int L,int r,int x)
{
int mid = L+ (r - 1) / 2;


    if(r>=L){


         printf("%d",r);

        if(a[mid] == x)
            return mid;
        if(a[mid]>x)
            return Bin_Search( a,L, mid-1, x);

            return Bin_Search( a,  mid+1,r, x);
    }
    return -1;
}

int main(void)
{

    int a[] = {2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,89};
    int  x=6;

    int n  = sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]);
    //printf("%d",n);
    int result = Bin_Search(a, 0 ,n-1 ,x);
//    (result == -1) ? printf("Item not present") : printf("Item present at index %d",result);
    return 0;
}
```

When I tried to run the above code I'm getting segmentation fault error. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: To me, in `int mid = l+ (r - 1) / 2;` it appears that you have 1 (one) instead of `l` (lower-case L).

Comment: similar error I updated  its name

Comment: The name does not matter as long as you refer to it correctly. The mid formula should read `int mid = left + (right - left) / 2;`.

Comment: Thank you. i got it now